# How do I use astyle within Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am using windows emacs with specifications below.

***GNU Emacs 23.0.91.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2009-02-26***

I want to be able to run astyle so it can reformat the code by using a key command or menu. What is some other equivalent in emacs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this might do:

```
(defun astyle-this-buffer (pmin pmax)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region pmin pmax
                           "astyle" ;; add options here...
                           (current-buffer) t 
                           (get-buffer-create "*Astyle Errors*") t))
```

This will run the "astyle" command on the selected region.

Or, you could simply use emacs' built-in code formatting by typing something like

```
 C-x h C-M-\
```

(I.e. select the whole buffer and run `indent-region`)

Comment: `indent-region` is not even close to being on par with astyle. It only indents and does not reformat the code (i.e. correct superfluous whitespace between braces, does not place braces and parens correctly and so on)