# How to autoformat (not just auto-indent) C++ code in emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs, coding-style, autoformatting

How can I auto-format C++ code in emacs following GNU-style?

There's this auto-newlines thing: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Auto_002dnewlines.html, but even when I set style to GNU it doesn't put the return value on a separate line from the function name.

I also want something that adds spaces between arguments in an argument-list.  And something I can "run" on code after I've written (not just moves things around as I type)

Answer (score 1):

[Already been answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801983/how-do-i-use-astyle-within-emacs) There's a tool called `astyle` (Artistic Style) that formats the code in C++.

```
(defun astyle-this-buffer (pmin pmax)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region pmin pmax
                           "astyle" ;; add options here...
                           (current-buffer) t 
                           (get-buffer-create "*Astyle Errors*") t))
```

Comment: I've been playing with astyle, and so far as I can tell, it does none of the above (spacing between arguments, newline after return value.  It doesn't even line wrap lines that are longer than 80 characters).  It's purely an indentation tool

Comment: @dspyz What about `clang-format`? http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html