# Run AStyle on current buffer, save and restore cursor position

Tags: emacs, elisp, code-formatting

I'm looking for a solution to apply code formatting and static code analysis on contents of current buffer in c++ mode. I'm planning to use [`AStyle`](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and [`CppCheck`](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/). Both tools need to be executed on current code. For example if I'm editing `foo.cpp` the function should run

```
astyle --arg1 --argn foo.cpp
```

And

```
cppcheck --arg1 --arg2 foo.cpp
```

What I already tried is a simple function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802495/275221) which is not working:

```
(defun astyle-this-buffer (pmin pmax)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region pmin pmax
                           "astyle" ;; add options here...
                           (current-buffer) t 
                           (get-buffer-create "*Astyle Errors*") t))
```

**Update:**

I found that the above code is compatible with Emacs23 while I'm using 24. So I used this instead:

```
(defun reformat-code ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) 
                           "astyle --options=~/.astylerc" t t))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-a") 'reformat-code)
```

Now it works and formats the code, though I can't find out how to save cursor's position and tell emacs to move that line.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the function isn't working? What's it doing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that reformatting tools like `astyle` will modify whitespace, but presumably nothing else.  (It's possible this is mildly wrong, like if they reformat a C macro then they must modify backslashes as well -- but that can also be taken into account.)

So, the way I would approach this would be to count how many non-whitespace characters appear before `(point)`, invoke `astyle`, revert the buffer (or whatever), and finally, starting from the start of the buffer, move forward that many non-whitespace characters.

This won't always be "the same", for example if point was in some whitespace that was modified -- but I think it ought to be reasonably close.

If you really want to just record the current line number and go back to that, you can use `line-number-at-pos` to get the current line number, and then `(goto-char (point-min))` and use `forward-line` to get back to the line.